# SpringSource Tool Suite and GWT without using ROO?

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I would like to know if anyone has any experience in using STS to create a Spring-enabled GWT web application *without* using Spring ROO.

There are 2 scenarios that I have.

1. I have an existing GWT application (not Spring-enabled, built in Eclipse 3.7) that I want to convert to a Spring-enabled GWT application in STS. I want STS to pick up that this is now Spring-enabled so that I can use the built-in features of STS for Spring.
2. Create a new GWT web application that is Spring-enabled in STS, but without using Spring ROO.

I have as of yet found no tutorials on how to do either. All the examples that point to creating a Spring-enabled GWT web application in STS use ROO to scaffold it for them.

Sorry if it is a bit unclear what I mean. Feel free to comment and I will try to explain more.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want the project nature to be converted to spring - get the spring enabled features in STS or do you also want the code / configuration required to connect GWT to spring backend?

Comment: Both. I have actually just got it working. Seems just manually adding the Spring libraries makes STS realize it's a Spring-enabled application.

Comment: To turn a project into a spring project you can right click, choose spring tools and Add spring nature.  I am not sure if adding the jars does it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gwt-spring-starter-app](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-spring-starter-app/) will help you create a maven project with spring & gwt integrated. You can then import it as a maven project into STS.  That should get everything correctly setup.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is pretty much what I have figured out for myself too.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to start with a Roo project, enable GWT, and then perform a push-in refactoring.  This will remove the Roo dependencies and what remains is a pure spring project that uses GWT.